# If a character has a light weapon that is made one size larger, is it treated as a one-handed weapon or a two-handed weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons

If a character has a light weapon that is made one size larger, would it be considered a 1-handed weapon, or a 2-handed weapon?

(I.e Weapons type being: Light, One Handed, Two Handed.)

Comment: How do you mean it’s made one size larger? As in, a weapon smithed to be Large to begin with? A weapon held by someone subject to *enlarge person*? Some reverse version of *shrink item* (which I don’t think exists but I could be wrong)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The players handbook (Page 113) has a small paragraph that answers your doubts -

> For instance, a Small greatsword (a two-handed weapon for a Small
>   creature) is considered a one-handed weapon for a Medium creature,
>   or a light weapon for a Large creature. Conversely, a Large dagger (a
>   light weapon for a Large creature) is considered a one-handed
>   weapon for a Medium creature, or a two-handed weapon for a Small
>   creature. If a weapon’s designation would be changed to something
>   other than light, one-handed, or two-handed by this alteration, the
>   creature can’t wield the weapon at all.

The designation of one-handedness or two-handedness or even light is based on both the size of the weapon and the size of the intended user

*Edited to add more info as requested.

On WotC message boards game designer Andy Colins has mentioned

> A character can wield a weapon within one size category at a -2 penalty.

So keep in mind there are penalties for using weapons not designed for your size, unless you use feats/features to get around this.

Comment: I upvoted the other answer for also mentioning the penalty the attacker suffers for using a weapon designed for a creature bigger or littler than the attacker. I'll upvote this one, too, if it's edited to mention that.

Comment: Well, Technically, If you take a light weapon to a Smith, and ask him to make a one-handed or a two handed version of the weapon, he is specifically making it to be designed for your size.

Answer (score 5):

If a weapon is light, but made for a creature of a size category larger than you, you treat it as a one-handed weapon (and also take a −2 penalty on attack rolls with it). So, for example, a halfling can wield a Medium shortsword as a one-handed weapon at a −2 penalty.

The only real reason to do this is if you are caught in a situation where you have no weapons sized correctly—that Medium shortsword’s damage is the same as a Small longsword’s, so the halfling would normally prefer to just use the Small longsword and avoid the −2 penalty.